# Pg backups curl latest dump from Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, curl, heroku

How can I download the latest backup from Heroku in a single line command.
The code has recently changed and doesn't seem to be of much help.
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgres-import-export

This creates a public url that i can open and download

$ heroku pg:backups public-url | cat

I need to use the curl command to download it, but it does not work

$ curl -o latest.dump `heroku pg:backups public-url | cat`

I have also tried to use the following and it could not resolve host.

```
heroku pg:backups capture && curl -o latest.dump `heroku pg:backups public-url | cat`

heroku pg:backups public-url && curl -o latest.dump `heroku pg:backups public-url | cat`
```

Please assist with the full command line.

Answer (score 5):

Ran into the same issue but was able to figure out a workaround:

```
$: heroku pg:backups capture --app APP_NAME
```

This will return a backup to something like b001

```
$: heroku pg:backups public-url b002 --app APP_NAME | cat
```

Returns url to dump

```
$  curl -o latest.dump URL_FROM_DUMP

$: pg_restore latest.dump -d YOUR_DB_NAME
```

Comment: You also may have to set your db ownership after running pg_restore

Answer (score 0):

This helped me import my Heroku Postgres db with all tables data(rows) to my local Postgres db:

1. Back up your database from Heroku

```
heroku pg:backups:capture -a your-app-name
```

2. Download the database from Heroku. The database will be downloaded as a latest.dump file to your computer

```
heroku pg:backups:download -a your-app-name
```

3. Import latest.dump to Postgres (your local database) (if this is the first dump, you don't need to specify the number of dump)

```
pg_restore --verbose --clean --no-acl --no-owner -h localhost -U your_local_db_username -d your_local_db_name latest.dump.[number of dump]
```

For number of dump look carefully on your console during step 2. For some reason Heroku documentation doesn't say anything about the number of dump.